# Problem loading 12.04 Ubuntu (running on low graphics mode please manually configure )

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I'm facing a problem in running Ubuntu on my laptop (i.e HP pavilion dm4- 1160us) after installing the lastest OS.

Your system is running in low-graphics mode, Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

I tried to update the grub by entering  as `i915.modeset xforcevesa` but when I reboot I still get same error

my system has Intel HD graphics

What do I do?

Comment: ***How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?*** does not currently address **intel-graphics** adequately, and does **not** resolve issues around Intel HD and GMA-45xx caused by recent updates.